# How can I change the size in TextField AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm doing a game and would like to increase the size of the score since it's too small
Thanks for the answer

This is the code for the score:

```
 var score_txt:TextField=new TextField();
 score_txt.textColor=0xFFFFFF;
 score_txt.x=142,3;
 score_txt.y=563,05;
```

note:the score must be TextField not TextFormat

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```js
score_txt.width = 100;
score_txt.height = 100;
```

Using a TextFormat could be easier:

```js
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.size = 15;

score_txt.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
score_txt.text = "your text"
```

Comment: Andrea Rega  Yes I have tried but it does not work for me, it only increases the size of the box, not the size of the letter  thank you to try help

Comment: is there a reason why not using a TextFormat?

Comment: If I use TextFormat it gives an error because of the score and gives variable not being string type or something like this

Comment: because this 1119: Acesso de propriedade possivelmente indefinida text por meio de uma referência com tipo estático flash.text:TextFormat.
score_txt.text=score.toString(); and some other thinks

Comment: did you try using a simple plain string instead of `score.toString();` ?

Comment: anyway here it is a [reference](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3text/) that could explain you better how to use the TextFormat component